# javafx TableView setSortPolicy - How to obtain sorting column and order on call event?

Tags: javafx

I have a TableView who pagination and sorting needs to be done on the server side. I started making an example that simulates the service calls using a simple thread.sleep.

I see that I can create a page factory that returns the different pages and call the backend service to retrieve the page.

I see that I can override setSortPolicy method and that this one is called when I click to sort the columns.

What I don't know is how to retrieve from the TableView object, what column has been clicked to apply the correct sorting and reflect this on the column headers too, currently my example below will always return the same sort order and not set the column header.

I will be very grateful if somebody could correct the example to reflect sorting correctly.

```
package example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Pagination;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class TestTablePagination extends Application {

private final static int dataSize = 10_023;
private final static int rowsPerPage = 1000;

private final TableView<Sample> table = createTable();
private final List<Sample> data = createData();
private Pagination pagination = null;

private List<Sample> createData() {
    List<Sample> data = new ArrayList<>(dataSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++) {
        data.add(new Sample(i, "foo " + i, "bar " + i));
    }

    return data;
}

private TableView<Sample> createTable() {

    TableView<Sample> table = new TableView<>();

    TableColumn<Sample, Integer> column1 = new TableColumn<>("Id");
    column1.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().id);


    TableColumn<Sample, String> column2 = new TableColumn<>("Foo");
    column2.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().foo);


    TableColumn<Sample, String> column3 = new TableColumn<>("Bar");
    column3.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().bar);


    table.getColumns().addAll(column1, column2, column3);
    table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
    return table;
}

private void simulateSlowServeSideCall() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Node createPage(int pageIndex) {
    table.getItems().clear();
    table.setSortPolicy( new Callback<TableView<Sample>, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call(TableView<Sample> tableView) {
            System.out.println("call called - Start");
            simulateSlowServeSideCall();
            Comparator<Sample> comparator = new Comparator<Sample>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Sample r1, Sample r2) {
                    if (tableView.getComparator() == null) {
                        return 0;
                    } else {
                        return tableView.getComparator().compare(r1, r2);
                    }
                }
            };


            int fromIndex = pagination.getCurrentPageIndex() * rowsPerPage;
            int toIndex = Math.min(fromIndex + rowsPerPage, data.size());
            System.out.println("call called - " + fromIndex + " " + toIndex);

            table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(data.subList(fromIndex, toIndex)));
            FXCollections.sort(table.getItems(), comparator);
            System.out.println("call called - Finish");
            return true;
        }
    });

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("createPage called - Start");
            simulateSlowServeSideCall();
            int fromIndex = pageIndex * rowsPerPage;
            int toIndex = Math.min(fromIndex + rowsPerPage, data.size());
            table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(data.subList(fromIndex, toIndex)));
            System.out.println("createPage called - Finish");
        }
    };
    thread.start();

    return new BorderPane(table);
}

@Override
public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
    pagination = new Pagination((data.size() / rowsPerPage + 1), 0);
    pagination.setPageFactory(this::createPage);

    Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(pagination), 1024, 768);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Table pager");
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    launch(args);
}

public static class Sample {

    private final ObservableValue<Integer> id;
    private final SimpleStringProperty foo;
    private final SimpleStringProperty bar;

    private Sample(int id, String foo, String bar) {
        this.id = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(id);
        this.foo = new SimpleStringProperty(foo);
        this.bar = new SimpleStringProperty(bar);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#getSortOrder-- and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#sortTypeProperty may help. And don't replace the items of a `TableView` that is currently in a scene from a thread other than the JavaFX application thread.

Comment: Thx Fabian, at the end I was able to do something with getSortOrder.